# How should I go about setting up vim-pathogen plug-ins for a group as a user with no root permissions?

Tags: vim, non-root-user, profile, vimrc

I do not have root permission on a linux cluster, but I would like to share my vim-plugins to all other members of a linux group using vim-pathogen.  We have a group-accessible folder, so that's where I can store all my vim-pathogen files; if I can maintain the files in my account I would prefer that (as I have everything done through a git repo).

Should I request the admin to source a vim file, change /etc/bashrc etc.? I want to ask in a way that would involve the admin the least and let me have ownership over the content of vim plug-ins.  For example, I have syntax files useful for software that we write, and would like to share them with my working group.

A vim blogger here shows in his .vimrc 
http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.com/2012/05/my-vimrc.html

```
" Initialize Plugin Manager
"---------------------------
" https://github.com/Raimondi/vim-pathogen
" Raimondi's pathogen allows multiple bundle dirs and
" provides a command interface to interrogate, enable and
" disable plugins.

call pathogen#infect('bundle/shared', 'bundle/local')

" bundle/shared contains plugins used by all
" bundle/local is for personal plugins
```

Would I just ask the admin to add in a line to source another vim file that I can manage for my group?

Comment: did you try to do put the bundle directory into the shared folder and put a symlink from there to your `.vim` directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here:

1. Git commit your .vim folder and have your group members clone it from there.
2. Have each group member symlink their /.vim to a shared folder.
3. Have each user modify their .vimrc to point to a shared folder like this:

   call pathogen#infect('foobundle/{}', '/foovim/foobundle/{}')

The first argument specifies the name of the folder (in case you want something other than "bundle") and the second passes a custom path. I would go with #1 as it would allow each team member to specify their own preferences as well.